# Move-insert/emplace from a vector into itself

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, stl, clang

Should this code print `empty` (Clang & GCC), or `not empty` (Visual C++)?

Should that change if I remove `reserve()`? What about using `emplace()` instead of `insert()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> > v;
    v.reserve(10);                              // Should this affect the output?
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(0));
    v.insert(v.begin(), std::move(v.front()));  // Does 'emplace' vs. 'insert' matter?
    printf("Element 0 is: %s\n", v[0] ? "not empty" : "empty");
    return 0;
}
```

Logically `not empty` makes more sense to me for `insert`, because the caller of `insert` is requesting movement from a particular object, and we need to ensure that's what we're moving from. Moreover, it seems silly for `reserve()` to affect which element ends up where.

However, that would imply both libstdc++ (GCC) and libc++ (Clang) are buggy, which doesn't seem likely.

Perhaps more interestingly, I'm less certain about `emplace`. I'm inclined to think using `emplace` should logically output `empty`, because the caller is requesting construction to occur *at in the object's correct place* ("emplace"), which requires movement to occur before construction.

What is the correct behavior of moving from a container into itself? Does it depend on the specifics of which of `insert`/`emplace`/`reserve` are called? Is it implementation-defined?

---

For what it's worth, [cppreference.com says the following for `emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace):

> If the required location has been occupied by an existing element, the inserted element is constructed at another location at first, and then move assigned into the required location.

but that goes against what both GCC and Clang do for `emplace`, as well as against my expectation above (which differs from my expectation for `insert`).

Comment: Maybe `insert` invalidates the `front` reference before it uses it to set the new value causing your code to have undefined behaviour?

Comment: Nothing to do with `shared_ptr`, `insert` invalidates the reference returned by `front`, what that's a reference to doesn't matter too much it's still undefined behaviour. The moved from state of `shared_ptr` is empty not undefined

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Why does `insert` invalidate the reference returned by `front`? Isn't the entire point of `reserve` to avoid that? In fact you could check its address and it should still point to the same location.

Comment: No `Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(), all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.`https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Very interesting, I had no idea references could get invalidated when there's no reallocation. That said though, that's not really important here, because you could add a level of indirection, and you'd still have the same dilemma. I'll try to update the question, but it's only going to make it (a lot) more complicated without really changing the substance...

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Actually, isn't that talking about invalidation *after* the call? Because the reference the caller is passing *is* in fact valid at the point of the call, right? That's the only precondition `insert` has as far as I can see. So I don't think that's it.

Comment: The reference doesn't magically become invalid at the end of the insert method it will become invalid at some point during the method, if it becomes invalid before the method has used it you won't get the expected result

Comment: @AlanBirtles: These stdlibs have *tests* to verify their handling of these cases. Look up `self_insert.cc`, `self_emplace.cc`... they literally check for self-insertion. That's because they're not undefined! These methods are only described in terms of their preconditions, postconditions, and invariants. The precondition of `insert` (which in this case is the validity of the reference) dictates what it requires the caller to guarantee *at the time of the call*. And the caller is indeed satisfying that condition. There are no other preconditions!

Comment: @user541686 Did you read the C++11 defect report for vector's emplace there? https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2164

Comment: @Secundi: I hadn't, thanks! Sounds like it should indeed work then? (*"args may directly or indirectly refer to a value in a."*)

Comment: @user541686 Yes, was my understanding this way too. I was surprised at all, that there's a possible difference between insert and emplace here for your case. C++ is a never ending learning story... :)

Comment: @Secundi: Yeah. The `emplace*` functions have always bothered me enough that I pretty much never use them—the function always seemed smelly to me. The only particular issue I could point to until 2 days ago was the bypassing of explicit constructors (which is by design, but often misused by users), but as of yesterday, now I see this potential semantic quirk.